# Way of saying on occasion of these occasions, which themselves occur on occasions?

Tags: word-choice

On occasion, Martha would cry. On occasion of these occasions, she would laugh afterwards...

Looking for something more neat / elegant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to think about what you meant quite a bit, as the sentence is difficult to understand! But now I get it. It's difficult to come up with a solution, though. I don't think there is an English phrase that conveys what you want to convey. Here are some options:

Sometimes, Martha would cry. And sometimes, after she cried, she would laugh.

On occasion, Martha would cry, and on a few of those occasional occasions, she would laugh afterwards. (You could use this in e.g. a novel, but not in a work of non-fiction, it's very contrived!)

Every now and then, Martha would cry. But sometimes she would laugh afterwards. (This is probably the simplest and therefore best solution. At least of the options I can come up with!)